# How to replace a particular length of characters with same length of unique digits

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to replace 16 digits in a file file.txt with 1111111111111111 i.e. 16 times 1 using UNIX command

Comment: What did you try for yourself towards solving this problem?

Comment: `I want to replace 16 digits in a file file.txt with 1111111111111111 i.e. 16 times 1 using UNIX command` Sure! No issues!

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]{16}/1111111111111111/g' f
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl:

```
perl -plE 's/\b\d{16}\b/q{1}x16/ge' < file.txt
```

from

```
line A 222222222222222   and 222222222222222    # fifteen
line B 3333333333333333  and 3333333333333333   # sixteen
line C 66666666666666666 and 66666666666666666  # seventeen
```

produce

```
line A 222222222222222   and 222222222222222    # fifteen
line B 1111111111111111  and 1111111111111111   # sixteen
line C 66666666666666666 and 66666666666666666  # seventeen
```

And the

```
perl -plE 's/\b(\d+)\b/q{1} x length($1)/ge'
```

from the same input will produce

```
line A 111111111111111   and 111111111111111    # fifteen
line B 1111111111111111  and 1111111111111111   # sixteen
line C 11111111111111111 and 11111111111111111  # seventeen
```